# How to pass a value as parameter using data-target = "# myModal"?

Tags: php, modal-dialog

i have this

```
<?php
if($natureza == 'CON'){
?>
<a data-toggle="modal" href="?param=<?=$id_serv?>#myModal" data-target="#myModal">
Click me</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Works, the modal opens perfectly

but,
how can i receive "param" value in modal ?

like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["param"])){
  $id = $_GET["param"];
}
```

I have no idea.

more

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
<tr class="info">
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Matrícula</th>
  <th>Nome</th>
  <th>Natureza</th>
  <th>Escolaridade</th>
  <th>Função</th>
  <th>Simb / Nível</th>
  <th>Curriculum</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

    <?php
    $sqlstat = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT                     
                                 id_serv,simb,nivel,func,mat,fnome,lnome,grau,natureza                                                                    
                                 FROM tbl_v_servidores WHERE local = '$sigla' ");
    $sqlstat->execute();
    $sqlstat->bind_result($id_serv, $simb, $nivel, $func, $mat, $fnome, 
                          $lnome, $grau, $natureza);
    $i =0;
    while ($sqlstat->fetch()) {

    $i = $i + 1;
      if($nivel == 0){
        $nivel = '';    
      }                                 
    ?>
      <tr>                                                    
        <td><?=$i?></td>
        <td><?=$mat?></td>
        <td><?=$fnome?> <?=$lnome?></td>
        <td><?=$natureza?></td>
        <td><?=$grau?></td>
        <td><?=$func?></td>                                         
        <td><?=$simb?> <?=$nivel?></td>
        <td>
           <?php
              if($natureza == 'CON'){
           ?>
           <a data-toggle="modal" href="?param=<?=$id_serv?>#myModal" 
           data-target="#myModal">Click me</a>
           <?php
              }
           ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php
      }
      ?>                                            
      </tbody>
      </table>
```

in window modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-   
labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-
             hidden="true">
                        X
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Curriculum</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          <?php
            if(isset($_GET["param"])){
              $id = $_GET["param"];
            }
```

then, in this way, I will use the PARAM variable to make a stop at the bank select and build the modal page

Comment: you want to access the param variable within the modal that pops up?

Comment: yes, i will using for select.

Comment: can you be more specific please.

Comment: So, i will try, because my english is not good.
<a data-toggle="modal" href="?param=<?=$id_serv?>#myModal" data-target="#myModal">Click me</a>
<?php
}
i will use the $id_serv in modal page.

selec * from table where id_serv = $id_serv;

Answer (score 0):

> but, how can i receive "param" value in modal ?

There is no way you can receive the value of the "param" unless you make another request.

And since the anchor

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="?param=<?=$id_serv?>#myModal" data-target="#myModal">
Click me</a>
```

uses a markup for the bootstrap modal query, it won't make a redirect request because all it does is trigger the visibility of the modal.

As far as I can uderstand the your problem, you are trying to get the value of "param" when you click the anchor. But then again, there is no way you can receive the value of the "param" unless you make another request.

Use ajax or jquery.

Comment: do you have example ?